# $3xy + x + y = z$ has a solution $x,y \neq 0$ for any $z\neq 0$, in the integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Conjecture.** The set $\{ 3xy + x + y : x,y \in \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0\} = \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$

How can one prove this?

**Attempt**:

$$
\vdots \\
3\cdot (-3)x + x - 3 = -8x - 3\\
3\cdot (-2)x + x - 2 = -5x - 2 \\
3\cdot (-1)x + x -1 = -2x - 1 \\
3\cdot 1 x + x + 1 = 4x + 1 \\
3\cdot 2x + x + 2 = 7x + 2 \\
3\cdot 3x + x + 3 = 10x + 3 \\
3\cdot 4x + x + 4 = 13x + 4 \\
\vdots 
$$

How can I prove that the above in coset form ($8(\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0) - 3$ for $-8x - 3$ e.g.) forms an "Erdos covering system" for $\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, because it's wrong.

The equation $3xy+x+y=z$ is equivalent to

$$(3x+1)(3y+1)=3z+1.$$

If $3z+1$ is prime, for example for $z=2$, then one of the factors (say $3x+1$) must be $\pm1$. $3x+1=-1$ has no integer solution, and $3x+1=1$ means $x=0$, which was excluded as a possibility.

That means any $z$ where $3z+1$ is a prime number is impossible to generate as $3xy+x+y$.

Comment: It covers all odd numbers at least I think, and just some of the evens.

Comment: $z=-1$ is not covered, as $-2$ is a prime, but otherwise the odd numbers seem covered. Generally, it just depends on if $3z+1$ has a non-trivial divisor of the form $3x+1$. That seems to exclude (in addition to primes), on first look, excactly the numbers that are a products of 2 primes $\equiv 2 \mod 3$. But that needs to be looked at in more detail, you could for example change the sign of the 2 factors.

Answer (score 1):

$$3xy+x+y =a\implies y = {a-x\over 3x+1}\implies 3x+1\mid a-x$$

But then $$ 3x+1 \mid 3(a-x) +(3x+1) = 3a+1$$ Because of simmetry we have also $3y+1\mid 3a+1$. So, if $x,y\ne 0$ then $|3x+1|>1$ and $|3y+1|>1$ and so $3a+1$ has at least to divisiors $\ne \pm 1$. This means that if $3a+1$ is prime there is no solution.